# How to detect if a string contains a specific Word

Tags: android, string, textview

I have this code :

```
if (currentLocation.distanceTo(myModel.getNearest()) < 900) {

        if (said != true) {

            String seriousWarning = (myModel.getNearest().getProvider());
            tts.speak(seriousWarning, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            said = true;


                 warningTxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
```

I would like to check if there a certain word in the seriousWarning string, knowing that (myModel.getNearest().getProvider()) is the title of the nearest GPS point to the device.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I was going to post an Answer, but then i took an arrow to the knee.

Answer (score 3):

try below piece of code:

```
boolean isPdf = stringValue.matches(".*\\b"STRING_NAME"\\b.*");
```

Comment: Additionally, I suggest to use this online tool http://regexr.com/ for creating more sophisticated patterns.

Answer (score 3):

You can use contains() method.

```
if(seriousWarning.contains("certainword"))
{
 //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to check if a string contains a substring.
This code snippet is from the android developer documentation.

```
 // String convenience methods:
 boolean sawFailures = s.matches("Failures: \\d+");
 String farewell = s.replaceAll("Hello, (\\S+)", "Goodbye, $1");
 String[] fields = s.split(":");

 // Direct use of Pattern:
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Hello, (\\S+)");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
 while (m.find()) { // Find each match in turn; String can't do this.
      String name = m.group(1); // Access a submatch group; String can't do this.
```

Answer (score 0):

use **indexOf("String to be checkecked");**

```
  if(seriousWarning.indexOf("String to be checkecked") > -1)
      {
          // your code
       }
```